# How can I use font-weight in my Next.js project?

Tags: next.js

I recently started using Next.js and after importing my fonts from 'next/font', I'm having some issues specifying what font weight to use for my elements

Here's how I approached the issue

```
# layout.jsx


import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";

const poppins = Poppins({
  weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
});



export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en"}>
      <body className={poppins.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering?

Comment: I've been able to sort it out, i was initially confused as to how to use font weights in next.js, I figured I just had to use the tailwind class names

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have correctly loaded your font into the project. Now, all you need to do is specify font weight using the [standard CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight). Bringing in those font weights only makes them available to you when writing CSS.